# MySQL - What data type should I use to store a Map field

Tags: java, mysql, dictionary

I have a field on my Java object that is type

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

and I am trying to figure out the best way to store it in a MySQL database. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what data type I should use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to learn about relational databases and normalization.

You won't be storing a Map in MySQL.  I can see a one-to-many relationship between two tables, where the parent is the table with the String key and the child is the one with many integer row values.

Answer (score 0):

you have two solutions
1- DB normalization, where you will have more then one table.
2- if you are (which is obvious) going to connect your database to a project, then maybe you can json encode the map, that will convert the map into a string, when you need it, decode it. do use this approach only if you are not processing the data within the database it self, if its just to store data, or communicate it using APIs or any sort of data communication you do.